# Camerax image analysis not giving proper image in wide angle cameras

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-camerax, google-mlkit, samsung

I am trying to analyse the image using CameraX. Some devices with a wide-angle camera do not provide proper images. The image in the analyser is entirely different from the image in the preview. I am using an aspect ratio of 4:3 in both the preview and image analyser. I am cropping the image based on the cropRect coming from the image proxy.

Please see the code snippet for the image analyser below. This issue can be reproduced on Samsung A23 devices.

```kotlin
val myPreview = Preview.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
                .build().also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(myPreviewView.surfaceProvider)
                }


val myImageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
  .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
  .setTargetAspectRatio(AspectRatio.RATIO_4_3)
  .build()
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(executer, MyImageAnalyser() { result ->
                    })
                }
```

###### Preview Image

[image: Image shown in the preview]

###### Image from analyser

[image: Image in the analyser after remove cropRect]

##### This issue can be reproducible in google sample as well with wide angle camera devices. eg:- Samsung A23

###### When I replace aspect ratio with resolution it is start working. Not sure what is root cause with aspect ratio.

```kotlin
val myPreview = Preview.Builder().setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
                .build().also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(myPreviewView.surfaceProvider)
                }


val myImageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
  .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
  .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
  .build()
                .also {
                    it.setAnalyzer(executer, MyImageAnalyser() { result ->
                    })
                }
```

Comment: how are you saving the image ?

Comment: converted imageproxy to bitmap and then saved.

Comment: can you add that method in the question also, since there is a chance that the bug can be in that method

Comment: Hi @Notron, this can be easily reproduced in the Google sample itself on the Samsung A23 device as well.

Please try the application linked below, and you will notice that the translation is not working inside the region of interest (the square box). However, it is working for text in some other places.

[Link to the application](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/translate-showcase)

Comment: I understand you, but unfortunately I don't have a Samsung A23 device to test on, but I have looked in the repository that you added and in TextAnalyzer.kt class line 72 the wide-angle case its mentioned together with a suggestion on how to handle that. Also the reason why I asked for the method that you are using to save the image is because  the saved image it looks a very small portion of the preview image, which leads me to think that part of the bug is there.

Comment: Save doesn't have any issues. It is normal file saving functionality using `FileOutputStream`.

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream)
 outputStream.close()

Comment: But if we try with resolution it will start work.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean with "if we try with resolution it will start work"

Comment: @Notron I have added with code with resolution in the issue.